# Loading yaml property file with ant

Tags: java, ant, yaml

Is there any built-in way to parse a yaml property file in ant?

When searching for a solution I only find the `LoadProeprties` task with which I could only load files in the `.properties` format:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html

Answer (score 1):

No. Ant only supports loading Properties and XML files (the latter via [XMLProperty](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html)). There are numerous ways to transform YAML into a Properties file though.